# Oracle SQL PIVOT : missing column and aggregated rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm trying to get a table which shows monthly attendance details for students. 
 What I have is a pivot which sums up the number of absences based on the student's course load. 
Say for instance I knew this student has 4 classes, all the time, regardless of school year or semester, [this would work perfectly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a18a7b/1/0):

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT SCHOOL_YEAR, TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE, 'mon') MNTH, ATTENDANCE_CODE 

FROM PERIOD_ATTENDANCE

WHERE PERSON_ID = '1234'
AND SCHOOL_CODE IN ('ESS', 'ASS', 'BSS')
) 


PIVOT (SUM(CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'L' THEN 1 END) as L, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'A' 
                AND MNTH IN ('sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan')
                THEN 1/4
                WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'A'
                AND MNTH IN ('feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun')
                THEN 1/4 END) as A
       FOR MNTH
       IN (     
                'sep',-- AS SEPTEMBRE,
                'oct',-- AS OCTOBRE,
                'nov',-- AS NOVEMBRE, 
                'dec',-- AS DECEMBRE,
                'jan', -- AS JANVIER, 
                'feb',-- AS FÉVRIER, 
                'mar',-- AS MARS,
                'apr',-- AS AVRIL,
                'may',-- AS MAI, 
                'jun'-- AS JUIN

            ) -- END <IN>
) -- END PIVOT
```

But since some students take fewer, or more than the average 4 courses per semester, I need to find a way to make that "4" (in "`THEN 1/4 END`") represent the actual number of courses the student is taking. 
I came up with a function which returns this number, but as soon as I plug it into the pivot the query only returns a single row, which displays a sum of all the student's absences from each year.

```
PIVOT (SUM(CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'L' THEN 1 END) as L, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'A' 
                    AND MNTH IN ('sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec', 'jan')
                    THEN 1/PKG_PROFILE_ÉLÈVE.GET_COURSE_COUNT(SCHOOL_YEAR, '123456789', 1)
                    WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'A'
                    AND MNTH IN ('feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun')
                    THEN 1/PKG_PROFILE_ÉLÈVE.GET_COURSE_COUNT(SCHOOL_YEAR, '123456789', 2) END) as A
```

It returns the following, and you'll notice the `school_year` column has vanished as well.

```
'sep'_L    'sep'_A    'oct'_L    'oct'_A    'nov'_L    'nov'_A    'dec'_L    'dec'_A    'jan'_L    'jan'_A    'feb'_L    'feb'_A    'mar'_L    'mar'_A    'apr'_L    'apr'_A    'may'_L    'may'_A    'jun'_L    'jun'_A
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    2        0.25          2                              0.75        2         0.25       1          1.75        2          1           7        0.75         1        0.25         1         0.25       1        0.25
```

This happens regardless of what's actually in the function. The function can 
simple be the following and it will still return a single aggregaded row.

```
FUNCTION GET_COURSE_COUNT(A_SCHOOL_YEAR VARCHAR2, A_PERSON_ID VARCHAR2, A_SEMESTER VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
NUM_COURSE NUMBER := NULL;

BEGIN
NUM_COURSE = 4;

RETURN NUM_COURSE;
END GET_COURSE_COUNT;
```

Does anyone know if this is caused because of the PIVOT function itself? Does the function somehow force the aggregation and sum of the rows?

 I've been looking around for two days now, and I can't seem to find a reason something like this would happen. It must be something obvious that I'm missing...

The actual function looks like this:

```
FUNCTION GET_COURSE_COUNT(A_SCHOOL_YEAR VARCHAR2, A_PERSON_ID VARCHAR2, A_SEMESTER VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER IS
NUM_COURSE NUMBER := NULL;

BEGIN 

SELECT
       COUNT( CASE --total des cours prit durant le semestre spécifié
              WHEN SEMESTER = A_SEMESTER 
              THEN SEMESTER END) AS SEMESTRE INTO NUM_COURSE

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SCT.SCHOOL_YEAR, 
                SCT.COURSE_CODE || '-' || SCT.COURSE_SECTION AS COURSE, 
                SC.TAKE_ATTENDANCE_FLAG, CM.SEMESTER

FROM SCHOOL_CLASSES SC, STUDENT_PROGRAM_CLASS_TRACKS SCT, CLASS_MEETINGS CM 

WHERE SCT.PERSON_ID = A_PERSON_ID
    AND SCT.SCHOOL_CODE IN ('ESS', 'ASS', 'BSS')
    AND SC.SCHOOL_CODE = SCT.SCHOOL_CODE
    AND SCT.SCHOOL_YEAR = A_SCHOOL_YEAR
    AND SC.SCHOOL_YEAR = SCT.SCHOOL_YEAR
    AND SC.CLASS_CODE = SCT.CLASS_CODE
    AND SCT.SCHOOL_CODE = CM.SCHOOL_CODE
    AND SCT.CLASS_CODE = CM.CLASS_CODE
    AND CM.SCHOOL_YEAR = SCT.SCHOOL_YEAR
    AND SCT.SCHOOL_YEAR_TRACK = CM.SCHOOL_YEAR_TRACK
    AND SCT.DEMIT_INDICATOR NOT IN ('9')


ORDER BY SCT.SCHOOL_YEAR, CM.SEMESTER, COURSE);


RETURN NUM_COURSE;
END GET_COURSE_COUNT;
```

Comment: So you want to calculate the attendance percentage per person, per month, and pivot the months? What is the `A` and `L` in the attendance column?

Comment: The A is for the absences and the L is for the lates. So Jan_A is the total of all the January absences for that school year (where absence should equal absence/# of classes the student is taking) and Jan_L is all the lates that student has for January. (Lates are just counted as 1 per late record in the period_attendance table. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: How do you know how many classes a person has? This is the `school_code`?

Comment: That's determined in the function get_course_count. I can provide a copy of what's actually in the function of you need. It's a few queries to a few different tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT SCHOOL_YEAR, TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE, 'MM') MNTH, ATTENDANCE_CODE, 
      GET_COURSE_COUNT(SCHOOL_YEAR, '123456789', 
        case when TO_CHAR(CALENDAR_DATE, 'MM') IN ('09','10','11','12','01') 
             then 1 else 2 end) gcc 
    FROM PERIOD_ATTENDANCE
    WHERE PERSON_ID = '1234' AND SCHOOL_CODE IN ('ESS', 'ASS', 'BSS')) 
PIVOT (
  SUM(CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'L' THEN 1 END) as L, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN ATTENDANCE_CODE = 'A' THEN 1/gcc END) as A
  FOR MNTH IN ('09','10','11','12','01','02','03','04','05','06'))
```

I think that every column used in pivot clause is aggregated, and in this case `school_year` is used as parameter for your function so it is agregated too - 
so solution should be moving function to base subquery. Also when I removed this parameter from function definition rows were not joined.

Please verify final results with your data and calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much; that solves the problem. It's a very elegant solution. :)